# How to have a separate click even for each UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have a `UITableView` using the prototype cells that generates a list. They all share the same Prototype cell as the data presented on them is the same, however the function that it should perform is not the same. All of these cells should be under the same section.

Should I use 6 different prototype cells and change which one I'm getting in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function based on the `NSINdexPath#row`, or is there a simpler way to register custom logic for when a cell becomes selected.

For example, lets say that my table view looks like this:

- Show Data - When clicked displays a popup window
- Goto Website - When clicked goes to the website
- Open application - When clicked opens another application
- Open view - When clicked opens another view

How would I handle that logic separately?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: which language objective-c or swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get a touch event for each cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // Show data
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        // Go to website
    }    
    /// etc 

}
```

Be sure to have set your tableViews `delegate` and `datasource` to your `viewController`, and have your viewController setup for this like so:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Must you extend(?) the base class `UITableViewController` to access this, as it's not available in `UITableViewDataSource` and I use a standard `UIViewController` considering my table-view is not my only element

Comment: see edit. that particular function is part of UITableViewDelegate, not UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Even though the method was not available, applying it straight to the UITableViewDataSource worked without the need of adding the UITableViewDelegate. Strange. Thanks, by the way. Will accept after timer

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.